# text.overflow ellipsis doesn't work on a paragraph?

Tags: css, ellipsis

I am creating a card with an image on top and a title (`h1`).

Under the image at the end is a long paragraph, but it overflows from my card (`p`). I used `overflow hidden`; it works, but when I use `text-overflow` it doesn't work: no points are showing.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px gray;
  transition: box-shadow 0.25s;
  display: block;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px gray;
}

.circle {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350&w=860');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: wrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <h1>hello i am the title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis sit amet nunc nec fermentum. Cras sit amet efficitur leo. Vivamus malesuada felis blandit odio semper maximus. Phasellus nec lacus enim. Aliquam lobortis nibh et ipsum aliquam,
      quis iaculis orci tincidunt. Curabitur sed orci porta, ultricies libero et, iaculis erat. Aenean tristique ex quis ante sagittis luctus. Aenean tempor accumsan erat, ut mollis dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent
      libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur a, imperdiet mollis dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur a, imperdiet scelerisque orci.mollis dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus
      aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur a, imperdiet mollis dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur a, imperdiet scelerisque orci.mollis
      dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur a, imperdiet mollis dolor. Nam rutrum neque sed lectus aliquet, in viverra elit cursus. Praesent libero lectus, ultricies a consectetur
      a, imperdiet scelerisque orci.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-overflow` needs other rules set to work: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: is [this the desired output](https://jsbin.com/qapacofubo/1/edit?html,css,output)?

Comment: Replace ```white-space: wrap;``` with ```white-space: nowrap;```.